# Auto Serial Number With Custom GridView Pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net, pagination

I am using custom pagination for the GridView along with Repeater. Here is the code that I've done so far:

```
Default.aspx:
<asp:Repeater ID="rptPager" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPage" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Text") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Value") %>'
        CssClass='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Enabled")) ? "page_enabled" : "page_disabled" %>'
        OnClick="lnkPage_Click" PostBackUrl='<%# "~/UI/SearchCity.aspx?page=" + Eval("Text") %>' OnClientClick='<%# !Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Enabled")) ? "return false;" : "" %>'></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

Default.aspx.cs:
private void BindGridView(int pageIndex) //Bind data
{
    List<Country> countryListView = null; //List type variable

    countryListView = aManager.AllCountryList(); //Assigns the data in the list calling the method

    totalRecordCount = countryListView.Count; //Counts total no. of record
    pageSize = 4; //Page size
    int startRow = pageIndex * pageSize; //Variable to assign the starting row

    detailsGridView.DataSource = countryListView.Skip(startRow).Take(pageSize); //Shows data in GridView
    detailsGridView.DataBind();
}

private void BindPager(int currentPageIndex) //Pagination
{
    double getPageCount = (double)((decimal)totalRecordCount / (decimal)pageSize);
    int pageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(getPageCount); //Count page

    List<ListItem> pages = new List<ListItem>(); //New list item

    /****Pagination starts ****/
    if (pageCount > 1) 
    {
        pages.Add(new ListItem("<<", "1", currentPageIndex > 0));

        for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
        {
            pages.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i != currentPageIndex + 1));
        }

        pages.Add(new ListItem(">>", pageCount.ToString(), currentPageIndex < pageCount - 1));
    }
    /****Pagination ends ****/

    rptPager.DataSource = pages;
    rptPager.DataBind();
}
```

The above works perfect. But the issue is when I use the following to generate auto serial number, it does not work properly:

```
<%#(Container.DataItemIndex+1)%>
```

I mean when I browse to page 2, the row count begins from 1 and the same for other pages. Is there any way to resolve or any other efficient technique to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Container.DataItemIndex is the index of the data item bound to the GridView and it can be used to determine the Row Index of the GridView Row. Therefore it is behaving as expected.

You have two choices:
1- Use your own rowcounter variable and store it in the session or viewpag objects.

2- better yet, let the database generate your row number instead. For example, if you are using Sql Server then do something like this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SalesYTD DESC) ROW_NUM, * FROM MYTABLE
```

Comment: I did try this to generate auto serial number: <asp:Label ID="labelSerialNo" runat="server"></asp:Label>. Then finally this, int serialNo = 1; protected void detailsGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) { if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) { if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(((Label)e.Row.FindControl("labelSerialNo")).Text)) { Label labelSerialNo = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("labelSerialNo"); labelSerialNo.Text = serialNo.ToString(); serialNo = serialNo + 1;  } } }. But it did not work. If possible, let me know if I missed something. I prefer the option 2 and worked.

Comment: serialNo should be persisted across page views. Therefore, you should save it and retrieve it when needed for it to maintain its value: `Session["serialNo"] = serialNo;` and `serialNo = int.Parse(Session["serialNo"].ToString());`

Comment: This is supposed to be in the same page. Is it required to keep the value in session?

Comment: If it is in the same page then use ViewState or ViewBag objects.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for the GridView custom pagination:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Serial Number">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# (detailsGridView.PageIndex * detailsGridView.PageSize) + (Container.DataItemIndex + 1) %>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is best solution
<%# (Container.DataItemIndex + 1) %>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).